# Regular Expression for TimeSpan in format "hh.mm"

Tags: asp.net, regex, timespan

I want to create RegularExpressionValidator for validation **TextBox** format **hh.mm**.

This expression works:

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]).[0-5][0-9]$
```

But if I insert `5454` in the TextBox it also passes, but it shouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` is a meta character in regular expressions that matches **any** character. If you want to match literally just a period, then you need to escape it:

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])\.[0-5][0-9]$
```

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to escape `.`

try

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])\.[0-5][0-9]$
```